# Using @ParameterObject or @PageableAsQueryParam to set description about Pageable in swagger doc

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, springdoc, pageable

right now, I am making swagger doc.

[swagger img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDZTy.png)

I want to customize that description about page, size and sort.

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public page<TestDTO> getTest(@ParameterObject Pageable pageable) {
      return page<TestDTO>
}
```

this is my brief code on controller.

is there a way to change that default description?

```
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.9'
```

this is my openapi implemenation in gradle.

I used @ParameterObject and @PageableAsQueryParam

but both only showed me the default description.